# How to use existing directory ~/.ssh in docker-compose named volumes?

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose, docker-volume

I want to map my `~/.ssh` to docker container `.ssh`. I have docker compose as

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  ssh-data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: ~/.ssh/
      o: bind

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: chagridsada/galera-mariadb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - "ssh-data:/app/.ssh/"
    environment:
      CLUSTER_NAME: galera-db-cluster
      CLUSTER_JOIN:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dev
      XTRABACKUP_PASSWORD: dev
```

but when I try to run the container, it gives error.

```
$ docker-compose up -d

Creating network "training_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "training_ssh-data" with local driver
Creating mysql ... error

ERROR: for mysql  Cannot start service mysql: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/training_ssh-data/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount ~/.ssh/:/var/lib/docker/volumes/training_ssh-data/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory

ERROR: for mysql  Cannot start service mysql: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/training_ssh-data/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount ~/.ssh/:/var/lib/docker/volumes/training_ssh-data/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

its trying to map with `/var/lib/docker/volumes/training_ssh-data/_data` in container, but in `docker-compose.yml` its mapped to `/app/.ssh/`.

If I change mapping to `~/.ssh:/app/.ssh`, then it will work fine, but I have to use `ssh-data` volume for other container too, so I have to create `named volume`.

Why its trying to map with `/var/lib/docker/volumes/training_ssh-data/_data` ?

Comment: This seems like a bad idea in the first place. Create whatever configuration you need in the image itself, and generate dedicated keys for the container rather than using your own keys.

Comment: We have to do a `ssh tunneling` from the container, and for that we need our key to map in container. If we generate new key in container, it might need to add for the `ssh tunneling`

Comment: @chepner consider it as different directory, which already exits, and see if we can use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (!?) the issue is that you're using a relative (`~/.ssh`) reference within the Docker Compose and you should should use an absolute reference

If I recall correctly, you can use environment variables within Docker Compose files and so could replace `~/.ssh` with `${HOME}/.ssh` on Linux.